# Pass in current model/scope to AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive setup like so

```
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: {
    savingModel: '='
  },
  templateUrl: '/templates/savingindicator'
};
```

I use it like so:

```
<saving-indicator saving-model="myModel"></saving-indicator>
```

I want to use this on legacy code which has all the properties of `myModel` on the current scope / controller.  How do I pass that into this directive?  Doing the following doesnt seem to work as `savingModel` is null

```
<saving-indicator></saving-indicator>
```

Comment: When you say "all the properties of myModel on the current scope", what exactly do you mean? Are they all separate variables or what? I'm confused because you if there is an equivalent of myModel, you could just change the var name. Does the legacy code not have it all in 1 variable?

Comment: The legacy code has all the right properties (`saved`, `saving` etc) that are usually in `savingModel` but they are all on the main controller (its legacy). Id rather not go around changing them all if I can't help it.

Comment: Ah yeah, I see. Well you could change the directives scope to take those instead(or along with) of the entire myModel, depending how flexible you need this to be. Maybe add them into the isolate scope and have overwrite savingModel properties in the directive IF they are there. Do you have multiple different pieces of legacy code or just this one? Maybe you could even put a directive in between to morph the data to whatever you need.

Comment: If your problem is that the directive expects `$scope.savingModel = {saved: false, saving: true}` and instead you have `$scope.saving = true; // ...`, can you not simply just use `$scope.savingModel = $scope;` and pass it along? (Though, personally, I say refactor and make it right instead. Also be careful about any recursive Object-copying functions, should any exist in the code.)

Comment: Thanks, please post this as an answer so I can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution, assuming your problem is that the directive expects `$scope.savingModel = {saved: false, saving: true}` and instead you have `$scope.saving = true; // ...`, would be just to attach a self-reference, and pass that:

`$scope.savingModel = $scope;`

This could, however, cause problems if you run any deep/recursive copying functions on the Object.

*The best solution would be to refactor the code and create the separate model Object, the above is just a quick hack to get things working in a pinch.*

Comment: Just FYI I re factored as, in hindsight, this was the best course of action

Comment: Great! Good to hear the proper solution won out. Future-Chris will surely thank you.